# Which EVM opcodes produce traces on GoEthereum

Tags: ethereum, opcode, go-ethereum, evm

I was reading through the Geth docs and noticed it mentioning [traces](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/dapp/tracing). It covered when traces occur and mentioned that logs are created anytime there are traces.

```
The simplest type of transaction trace that Geth can generate are raw EVM opcode traces.
For every VM instruction the transaction executes, a structured log entry is emitted,
containing all contextual metadata deemed useful. This includes the program counter, 
opcode name, opcode cost, remaining gas, execution depth and any occurred error.
```

Are these logs different than the event logs emitted from the `LOG` opcode? Which opcodes result in traces? Can anyone provide some clarity on the logs created from opcodes and the `LOG` opcode?

Comment: I think this is something you should check from GoEthereum codebase yourself, as it is implementation and version specific.

Answer (score 0):

The structured logs it is referring to are different from those emitted by the `log` opcode.  The text is refers to profiling information which shows internals of the EVM during executing.  Using the command-line `evm` tool provide with Geth you can see this quite easily.  For example, a command like this:

```bash
evm --code="0x60006000f3" --json run
```

This produces the following trace information:

```json
{"pc":0,"op":96,"gas":"0x2540be400","gasCost":"0x3","memSize":0,"stack":[],"depth":1,"refund":0,"opName":"PUSH1"}
{"pc":2,"op":96,"gas":"0x2540be3fd","gasCost":"0x3","memSize":0,"stack":["0x0"],"depth":1,"refund":0,"opName":"PUSH1"}
{"pc":4,"op":243,"gas":"0x2540be3fa","gasCost":"0x0","memSize":0,"stack":["0x0","0x0"],"depth":1,"refund":0,"opName":"RETURN"}
{"output":"","gasUsed":"0x6","time":76459}
```

Here you can see information about the state of the EVM as it executes the bytecode program, such as its currently `pc` value, `stack` contents, etc.  With the `evm` tool you can also see other information such as memory with the command `--nomemory=false`, etc.